# Существуют ли какие то общепринятые стандарты касательно верстки шаблонов для почтовой рассылки?

Tags: html, css, html5, email, sendmail

Существуют ли какие то общепринятые стандарты касательно верстки шаблонов для почтовой рассылки?

Буду рад ссылкам на ресурсы, где эти стандарты описаны.

Comment: Очень много нюансов, все их думаю не знает никто (и уж тем более нет статей полноценно покрывающих эту тему), на хабре есть достаточно хорошая [СТАТЬЯ](https://habrahabr.ru/post/252279/), но и там я не все ответы смог найти.

Answer (score 1):

1. Изображения вставлять только как , background-imagе не везде работает
2. Использовать только табличную верстку
3. ячейки выравнивать с помощью атрибутов aligh="", valign=""
4. не использовать margin , padding. все отступы задавать с помощью ячеек td c 
   атрибутами width="" или height=""(указывается число без px)
5. избегать использование тегов div span p и т.д.
6. стили прописывать инлайново в table, td через атрибут style=""
7. шрифты подключать через cdn

возможно есть более верный подход, буду рад узнать